# Invalid device error while recording sound with Port audio

Tags: c++, windows, audio, audio-recording, portaudio

I am using port audio 19 to record sound on my Windows 10 system.

Now the issue is that one of my devices (Jabra headphone) is shown as compatible for 2 different host API types (MME and Windows WDM-KS) but when I try to record sound through the device for host API Windows WDM-KS, the Pa_Openstream call fails with error Invalid Device (-9996).
Am I missing something while checking for compatibility? Ideally if the device is shown twice then it should also be able to record with both the options.
Also I would like to display the device only once in drop down. I can just check if the name is already present in the drop down but I would prefer if I could filter at the time of populating the deviceList itself. Is there any method other than just checking the name already present in the list?

I am using this code to populate the audio input devices in a drop down.

```
struct DeviceInfo
{
    QString name;
    int index;
}


QList<DeviceInfo> deviceList;

const PaDeviceIndex deviceCount = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i)
{
    const PaDeviceInfo* device = Pa_GetDeviceInfo((PaDeviceIndex)i);

    if (device && device->maxInputChannels > 0)
    {
        if (IsInputDeviceCompatible(i))
        {
            DeviceInfo info;
            info.index = i;
            info.name = device->name;

            deviceList.push_back(info);
        }
    }
}

bool IsInputDeviceCompatible(int index)
{
    PaStreamParameters inputParam;
    inputParam.device = index;
    inputParam.channelCount = 1;
    inputParam.sampleFormat = paInt16;
    inputParam.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = 0;
    inputParam.suggestedLatency = 0;

    PaError err = Pa_IsFormatSupported(&inputParam, nullptr, 22050);

    return err == paNoError;
}
```